# Change CSS background image for solid color background with @media

Tags: css, mobile, media

I'm trying to get this CSS code to change the image background to a solid color for mobile (width:992px).

`.herogirl{position:relative;width:100vw;height:70vh;display:flex;justify-content:left;align-items:center}.herogirl::before{content:"";position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;background:url(/templates/assets/img/hero-header-lady.jpg);background-color: #b7b5b8; !important;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:cover;background-position:center center;filter:brightness(100%);border-radius:5px}`

I've tried adding @media variables to several parts but no go.

`.herogirl{background-color:#b7b5b8:@media screen and (min-width:992px);position:relative;width:100vw;height:70vh;display:flex;justify-content:left;align-items:center}.herogirl::before{content:"";position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;background:url(/templates/CloudSave-child/assets/img/hero-header-lady.jpg);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:cover;background-position:center center;filter:brightness(100%);border-radius:5px}`

Answer (score 0):

In the before definition put the background color to a solid color.

In a media query 992px, you put the background url

```
.herogirl {
            position: relative;
            width: 100vw;
            height: 70vh;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: left;
            align-items: center
        }
        .herogirl::before {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: red !important;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center center;
            filter: brightness(100%);
            border-radius: 5px
        }

        @media (min-width: 992px) {
            .herogirl::before {
                background: url(https://image-placeholder.com/images/actual-size/1600x1200.png);
            }
        }
```

*in the code here I put a placeholder as image, and color red if under 992px*

Don't forget to add in the beginning of your HTML, just under  the following (in fact as you soon you play with box, media..., put it):

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

I've added a snippet (I put a 90vh for the before otherwise in this snippet case, because relative-absolute, height 100% would compute to 0):

```css
.herogirl {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
        }
        .herogirl::before {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 90vh;
            background-color: #333333;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center center;
            background-clip: content-box;
            filter: brightness(100%);
            border-radius: 5px
        }

        @media (min-width: 992px) {
            .herogirl::before {
                background-image: url(https://webhost.pro/templates/CloudSave-child/assets/img/hero-header-lady.jpg);
            }
        }
```

```html
<div class="herogirl">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry I added your code and removed the old CSS for .herogirl and it changed the image perspective which is fine but it still shows the background image on my phone after being refreshed. Here is a page with the code, in case it helps: https://webhost.pro/services/website-builder/ And yes it has the viewpoint meta

Comment: I checked your link, when inspecting, I don't anywhere in your CSS the @media definition.